# Start MapFragment from fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

Is there a way to start a *MapFragment* from inside a fragment, the way you can start another activity from inside an activity? I'm trying to do that using the code below but it doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong or is it simply not possible to do?

```
Intent mymapintent = new Intent(this, MyMapFragment.class);
startMyMapFragment(mymapintent);
```

Comment: Fragments are like Views with expressed lifecycles. You can't start one, but you can add one to your current view.

Comment: You don't create fragments with intents.

Comment: Start over and read this first: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/